# time complexity ( studying for exam)

Tags: time-complexity

I am currently studying to an examen in algorithms and I am trying to solve a question about time complexity in java, but can't really figure out how to do it. I am suppose to calculate the expected time complexity. N is a positive integer.

```
for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j=i+1; j < N; i++) {
    int x=j+1; int h=N-1; int k;
        while(x<h) {
        k=(x+h)/2;
           if (a[i]+a[j]+a[k] == 0) { cnt++; break;}
           if (a[i]+a[j]+a[k]  < 0) x=k+1;
           else h=k-1;
}}
```

The first for loop should run N times and the second should run N-1. Since x is j+1 I guessed that x= N-2. I dont know how to think after that with the while loop or if I have done anything right. Would really appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

Create your time complexity function in parts.

```
for (int i=0; i < N; i++) //Takes linear O(n)
  for (int j=i+1; j < N; i++) { //Takes linear O(n) and in computer science we can safely assume -1 is irrelevant at N-1 in big O notation 
    int x=j+1; int h=N-1; int k; // 3 x O(1)
    while( x < h ) { // Worst case is when j equals i + 1 where i = 0 so x is at lowest 2 and h equals to N-1 so h depends on N. So again loop takes linear O(n) time.
      k=(x+h)/2; // Takes O(1) time
       if (a[i]+a[j]+a[k] == 0) { // Takes O(1) time and if this gives true we do break from the while loop
         cnt++; // Takes O(1) time
         break; // Takes O(1) time
       }
       if ( a[i]+a[j]+a[k]  < 0 ) { // Takes O(1) time
         x=k+1; // Takes O(1) time
       } else {
         h=k-1; // Takes O(1) time
       }
    }
  }
}
```

So in summary T(N) equals to O(N^3) and Ω(N^2)
More specific T(N) = N * N-1 * N-2 + 10 and this last while loop in avarage takes O(N/2) time but still in computer science it is same as O(N).

We are only interested in worst and best cases.

To confuse even more big O notation actually
T(N)=O(g(N)) means this:

[image: T(N)=O(g(N))]

I hope this answer helps even little bit...